# webbrowser in new thread and close the same thread after execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have the following code:

```
    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread mainThread = new Thread(core);
        mainThread.Start("http://wikipedia.org");
    }

    private void core(object url)
    {
        Exec((string)url);
    }

    void Exec(string url)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
            {
                wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                browserPanel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { browserPanel.Controls.Add(wb); });
                browserPanel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { browserPanel.Refresh(); });

                wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

                wb.DocumentCompleted += (sndr, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sndr as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
                        return;


                    Console.WriteLine(wb.DocumentTitle);

                    // Close the current instance of the WB control and exit the current thread
                    wb.Dispose();
                    Application.ExitThread();

                    Console.WriteLine("Closed!");
                };
                wb.Navigate(url);
                Application.Run();
            }
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Name = "Browser thread";
        th.Start();
        th.Join();
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to kill the thread after each execution and create new one(with new instance of the browser control), but the form is just disappearing. Visual studio keeps the program running but the form is gone.

The problem is that I'm adding the browser to a panel so I can see what's going on. I've found these lines makes the form to disappear.

```
wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
browserPanel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { browserPanel.Controls.Add(wb); });
browserPanel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { browserPanel.Refresh(); });
```

If I remove/comment these lines everything works as expected. Is there any way to keep the browser "painted" on the form(panel) and still exit the thread?

Comment: The application.exitthread does this: Exits the message loop on the current thread and closes all windows on the thread.  So the problem is that you are killing the GUI thread. After the wb.dispose just create a new one and get rid of the exitthread.  Or instead of disposing it just create a new one...  but you'll need to check the memory to see if it's a good idea.

Comment: I've tried to just dispose the control but because of some other operations that I'm doing with files(in use), I feel the thread stays opened and "uses" them.

Comment: I think I was referring to the Application.ExitThread statement as the primary culprit.

Comment: Yes, it is, for closing the GUI thread. But if I don't use it, the browser thread stays alive(not actually sure).

Comment: Try this, before you dispose of the WB put in this line of code: WB = new WebBrowser();  Then dispose it.  You have to remove the Application.ExitThread otherwise it will do exactly what it's being told to do which is "Close the program'